# error with module uglify-js during gulp compression js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, zurb-foundation

I am using foundationpress. And there build in gulp with compression modules. When i am using "npm start", i get liverealod and my files compressing in fly and everything is works. But when i need deploy my site, i am using "npm run package" and then my terminal throw a error with uglify-js module.

```
    { Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Ampps\www\atmosfera\wp-content\themes\FoundationPress\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1534:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Ampps\www\atmosfera\wp-content\themes\FoundationPress\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1542:11)
    at parse_error (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Ampps\www\atmosfera\wp-content\themes\FoundationPress\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1667:9)
    at Object.next_token [as input] (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Ampps\www\atmosfera\wp-content\themes\FoundationPress\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1946:9)
    at next (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Ampps\www\atmosfera\wp-content\themes\FoundationPress\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2075:25)
    at maybe_conditional (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Ampps\www\atmosfera\wp-content\themes\FoundationPress\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2834:13)
    at maybe_assign (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Ampps\www\atmosfera\wp-content\themes\FoundationPress\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2856:20)
    at expression (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Ampps\www\atmosfera\wp-content\themes\FoundationPress\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2875:20)
    at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Ampps\www\atmosfera\wp-content\themes\FoundationPress\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2608:26)
    at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (F:\Ampps\www\atmosfera\wp-content\themes\FoundationPress\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2792:19)
  message: 'F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\app.js: Unexpected character \'`\'',
  fileName: 'F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\app.js',
  lineNumber: 105,
  stack: 'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1534:18)\n    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1542:11)\n    at parse_error (eval at <anonymous> (F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1667:9)\n    at Object.next_token [as input] (eval at <anonymous> (F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1946:9)\n    at next (eval at <anonymous> (F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2075:25)\n    at maybe_conditional (eval at <anonymous> (F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2834:13)\n    at maybe_assign (eval at <anonymous> (F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2856:20)\n    at expression (eval at <anonymous> (F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2875:20)\n    at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2608:26)\n    at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (F:\\Ampps\\www\\atmosfera\\wp-content\\themes\\FoundationPress\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2792:19)',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-uglify' }
[18:49:23] Version: webpack 3.10.0
 Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
app.js  1.15 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  app
[18:49:41] gulp-imagemin: Minified 102 images (saved 1.6 MB - 13%)
[18:49:41] Finished 'images' after 22 s
[18:49:41] The following tasks did not complete: package, build, <parallel>, webpack:build
[18:49:41] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

here is my gulpfile.babel.js file:

```js
'use strict';

import plugins       from 'gulp-load-plugins';
import yargs         from 'yargs';
import browser       from 'browser-sync';
import gulp          from 'gulp';
import rimraf        from 'rimraf';
import yaml          from 'js-yaml';
import fs            from 'fs';
import dateFormat    from 'dateformat';
import webpackStream from 'webpack-stream';
import webpack2      from 'webpack';
import named         from 'vinyl-named';
import log           from 'fancy-log';
import colors        from 'ansi-colors';

// Load all Gulp plugins into one variable
const $ = plugins();

// Check for --production flag
const PRODUCTION = !!(yargs.argv.production);

// Check for --development flag unminified with sourcemaps
const DEV = !!(yargs.argv.dev);

// Load settings from settings.yml
const { BROWSERSYNC, COMPATIBILITY, REVISIONING, PATHS } = loadConfig();

// Check if file exists synchronously
function checkFileExists(filepath) {
  let flag = true;
  try {
    fs.accessSync(filepath, fs.F_OK);
  } catch(e) {
    flag = false;
  }
  return flag;
}

// Load default or custom YML config file
function loadConfig() {
  log('Loading config file...');

  if (checkFileExists('config.yml')) {
    // config.yml exists, load it
    log(colors.bold(colors.cyan('config.yml')), 'exists, loading', colors.bold(colors.cyan('config.yml')));
    let ymlFile = fs.readFileSync('config.yml', 'utf8');
    return yaml.load(ymlFile);

  } else if(checkFileExists('config-default.yml')) {
    // config-default.yml exists, load it
    log(colors.bold(colors.cyan('config.yml')), 'does not exist, loading', colors.bold(colors.cyan('config-default.yml')));
    let ymlFile = fs.readFileSync('config-default.yml', 'utf8');
    return yaml.load(ymlFile);

  } else {
    // Exit if config.yml & config-default.yml do not exist
    log('Exiting process, no config file exists.');
    log('Error Code:', err.code);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

// Delete the "dist" folder
// This happens every time a build starts
function clean(done) {
  rimraf(PATHS.dist, done);
}

// Copy files out of the assets folder
// This task skips over the "images", "js", and "scss" folders, which are parsed separately
function copy() {
  return gulp.src(PATHS.assets)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets'));
}

// Compile Sass into CSS
// In production, the CSS is compressed
function sass() {
  return gulp.src('src/assets/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: PATHS.sass
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: COMPATIBILITY
    }))

    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.cleanCss({ compatibility: 'ie9' })))
    .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe($.if(REVISIONING && PRODUCTION || REVISIONING && DEV, $.rev()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/css'))
    .pipe($.if(REVISIONING && PRODUCTION || REVISIONING && DEV, $.rev.manifest()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browser.reload({ stream: true }));
}

// Combine JavaScript into one file
// In production, the file is minified
const webpack = {
  config: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules(?!\/foundation-sites)/,
        },
      ],
    },
    externals: {
      jquery: 'jQuery',
    },
  },

  changeHandler(err, stats) {
    log('[webpack]', stats.toString({
      colors: true,
    }));
    
    browser.reload();
  },

  build() {
    return gulp.src(PATHS.entries)
      .pipe(named())
      .pipe(webpackStream(webpack.config, webpack2))
      .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uglify()
        .on('error', e => { console.log(e); }),
      ))
      .pipe($.if(REVISIONING && PRODUCTION || REVISIONING && DEV, $.rev()))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/js'))
      .pipe($.if(REVISIONING && PRODUCTION || REVISIONING && DEV, $.rev.manifest()))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/js'));
  },

  watch() {
    const watchConfig = Object.assign(webpack.config, {
      watch: true,
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    });

    return gulp.src(PATHS.entries)
      .pipe(named())
      .pipe(webpackStream(watchConfig, webpack2, webpack.changeHandler)
        .on('error', (err) => {
          log('[webpack:error]', err.toString({
            colors: true,
          }));
        }),
      )
      .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/js'));
  },
};

gulp.task('webpack:build', webpack.build);
gulp.task('webpack:watch', webpack.watch);

// Copy images to the "dist" folder
// In production, the images are compressed
function images() {
  return gulp.src('src/assets/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.imagemin({
      progressive: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/images'));
}

// Create a .zip archive of the theme
function archive() {
  var time = dateFormat(new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd_HH-MM");
  var pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));
  var title = pkg.name + '_' + time + '.zip';

  return gulp.src(PATHS.package)
    .pipe($.zip(title))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('packaged'));
}

// PHP Code Sniffer task
gulp.task('phpcs', function() {
  return gulp.src(PATHS.phpcs)
    .pipe($.phpcs({
      bin: 'wpcs/vendor/bin/phpcs',
      standard: './codesniffer.ruleset.xml',
      showSniffCode: true,
    }))
    .pipe($.phpcs.reporter('log'));
});

// PHP Code Beautifier task
gulp.task('phpcbf', function () {
  return gulp.src(PATHS.phpcs)
  .pipe($.phpcbf({
    bin: 'wpcs/vendor/bin/phpcbf',
    standard: './codesniffer.ruleset.xml',
    warningSeverity: 0
  }))
  .on('error', $.util.log)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});

// Start BrowserSync to preview the site in
function server(done) {
  browser.init({
    proxy: BROWSERSYNC.url,

    ui: {
      port: 8080
    },

  });
  done();
}

// Reload the browser with BrowserSync
function reload(done) {
  browser.reload();
  done();
}

// Watch for changes to static assets, pages, Sass, and JavaScript
function watch() {
  gulp.watch(PATHS.assets, copy);
  gulp.watch('src/assets/scss/**/*.scss', sass)
    .on('change', path => log('File ' + colors.bold(colors.magenta(path)) + ' changed.'))
    .on('unlink', path => log('File ' + colors.bold(colors.magenta(path)) + ' was removed.'));
  gulp.watch('**/*.php', reload)
    .on('change', path => log('File ' + colors.bold(colors.magenta(path)) + ' changed.'))
    .on('unlink', path => log('File ' + colors.bold(colors.magenta(path)) + ' was removed.'));
  gulp.watch('src/assets/images/**/*', gulp.series(images, browser.reload));
}

// Build the "dist" folder by running all of the below tasks
gulp.task('build',
  gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(sass, 'webpack:build', images, copy)));

// Build the site, run the server, and watch for file changes
gulp.task('default',
  gulp.series('build', server, gulp.parallel('webpack:watch', watch)));

// Package task
gulp.task('package',
  gulp.series('build', archive));
```

here is my config.yml file

```
    # Browsersync config
BROWSERSYNC:
  # URL of local development server goes here (ex. http://localsite.dev)
  url: "http://localhost/atmosfera/"

# Autoprefixer will make sure your CSS works with these browsers
COMPATIBILITY:
  - "last 2 versions"
  - "ie >= 9"
  - "ios >= 7"

# Set to true if you want static asset revisioning, helpful for cache busting
REVISIONING: false  

# Gulp will reference these paths when it copies files
PATHS:
  # Path to dist folder
  dist: "dist"
  # Paths to static assets that aren't images, CSS, or JavaScript
  assets:
    - "src/assets/**/*"
    - "!src/assets/{images,images/**/*,js,js/**/*,scss,scss/**/*}"
  # Paths to Sass libraries, which can then be loaded with @import
  sass:
    - "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss"
    - "node_modules/motion-ui/src"
  # Paths to JavaScript entry points for webpack to bundle modules
  entries:
    - "src/assets/js/app.js"
  # Paths for the package task to include/exclude in .zip archive
  package:
    - "**/*"
    - "!**/node_modules/**"
    - "!**/packaged/**"
    - "!**/src/**"
    - "!**/codesniffer.ruleset.xml"
    - "!**/composer.json"
    - "!**/composer.lock"
    - "!**/config.yml"
    - "!**/config.default.yml"
    - "!**/gulpfile.babel.js"
    - "!**/package.json"
    - "!**/package-lock.json"
    - "!**/webpack.config.js"
  # Paths for PHP CodeSniffer
  phpcs:
    - "**/*.php"
    - "!wpcs"
    - "!wpcs/**"
```

I cant deploy my site because of that problem. I am new at node js and gulp can anyone say how to fix it?

Comment: read : message, fileName and lineNumber

Comment: Search "Did you forget to signal async completion?" and gulp.  For instance, your gulp tasks probably need return statements or another method to signal aync completion.  Obviously you may have other issues in your gulpfile.js which you should post in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have solved by https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress/issues/1219#issuecomment-361344578

The problem is about windows paths.